# Add media and attach images to pages

Tags: plugin-development, images

I have this problem with attaching images and add media.

**ADD MEDIA**

1. Go to page
2. Click on "Add media"
3. Insert an image
4. Image shows in editor, but when I go to the page and do the below code it doesn't update.

**ATTACH IMAGE**

1. Go to media
2. find image and attach a page
3. This works ok, but once that image is attached to that page I cannot attach it to another

**CODE**

```
 $attachments = get_attached_media( 'image', $page_id);

$images = array();
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) 
{   
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
            if($image)
                $images[] = $image;
}

wp_localize_script( 'custom-js-script', 'images', $images);
```

**1. I want to use add media because I can then I can re-use images on different pages BUT IT DOESN'T WORK how can I get the images as the above code?**

**2. If I can't do the above how can I re-use attachments?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why:**

In WordPress one can only attach a file to a **single** parent post. This is because the relationship is stored in the `wp_post` table as the `post_parent`  field. It's   a `bigint(20)` type so it can only contain a single number (ID).

**Workaround:**

We would need to cook something ourselves, maybe that could be by using a custom taxonomy for our attachments or perhaps using custom fields (post meta) to store the attachments IDs?

Or we could try [some plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=attachments) out there that can help us re-using our attachments.

Comment: I decided to use insert images (using add media) rather than attach and then get the image src from the post_content with a regex. Not as clean as the attach way but solves all the problems